# Java code for file output is not working

Tags: java

Here i have written a program. I want to get input by a scanner from system. Then I want to show output from file. But after giving input , a message " The file is modyfied by another program " is shown. But i cannot see anything in this file. Please give me a suggestion to solve the problem.

```
package eighthLecture;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Filetester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File outFile = new File("C:/Users/nafiulislam/Desktop/naficlass.txt");
        try {

            FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter(outFile);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            while(scanner.hasNext()){
            String tempString = scanner.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println(tempString);
            fileWriter.write(tempString);
        }
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you opened the file in an editor or similar? If yes then it's probably locked by that program, i.e. Java can't write to it. Please post the exact strack trace you get.

Comment: @Thomas is right... your code works even with various executions simultaneously... you must have file opened with another application. If not, restarting computer will fix the problem

Comment: Couple of improvements: `File inpFile = new File("C:/1/one.txt")` line is not used.... remember to close the `Scanner` after using it

Comment: I have restarted my computer but it is not working